# PHP Class member access on instantiation

Tags: php, oop

I have a problem with the new syntax of PHP 5.4
My code with member access on instantiation

```
$oClass = (new Foo)->bar();
$oClass->bar2();
```

I get this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bar2() on a non-objec

Why?

EDIT: I added `return $this;` in the method Foo::bar() and now it works

Comment: What does `(new Foo)->bar()` evaluate to?

Comment: Instead of editing your question, please accept the answer below provided by your peers here on this website. That will also mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 9):

My guess is that you think `$oClass` will contain an object. This is not the case; it contains the result of the function `bar()`.

If you want to access `bar2()` you need to do the following as normal:

```
$oClass = new Foo;
$oClass->bar();
$oClass->bar2();
```

Class member access on instantiation is for when you only need to access a single member of the object breifly, and then you do not need the object any more.

**Edit:**
I've possibly overlooked something.

Consider the following code:

```
class Test {
    public function foo() {
        return $this;
    }

    public function bar() {
        return 'oh hai';
    }
}

$t = (new Test)->foo();

print $t->bar();
```

In this case you will still be able to access the object, because the function `foo()` returns `$this` and you are storing it, maintaining the reference to the object.

If you really want to, you can also chain methods like so:

```
print (new Test)->foo()->bar();
```

Answer (score -2):

How about this?

```
($oClass = new Foo)->bar();
$oClass->bar2();
```

Comment: Parse error. You should try your code first before offering it as an answer.